# How to make public chat using Django Channels WITHOUT AuthMiddlewareStack?

Tags: django, channel

UPDATED:
I want to implement chat with mobile app. Mobile app user are not Django users, so Django cant auth them.

I cant understand how to do not use AuthMiddlewareStack in routing. Now my code is:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url(r"leadusers/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<chatid>[\w-]+)/$", LeadUserConsumer, name='leaduser_consumer'),
                ]
            )
        ),
    ),
})
```

I tried to remove just this class AllowedHostsOriginValidator - doesnt work.

May be the answer in creating custom authentication?

```
class QueryAuthMiddleware:
"""
Custom middleware (insecure) that takes user IDs from the query string.
"""

def __init__(self, inner):
    # Store the ASGI application we were passed
    self.inner = inner

def __call__(self, scope):
    # Look up user from query string (you should also do things like
    # check it's a valid user ID, or if scope["user"] is already populated)
    user = User.objects.get(id=int(scope["query_string"]))
    close_old_connections()
    # Return the inner application directly and let it run everything else
    return self.inner(dict(scope, user=user))
```

May be somebody knows? Help, please.

Comment: Please take a minute and read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/10400050) Instead, try to describe how you're trying to use the functionality and what's not working/what you want to happen.

Comment: @Johan Well, I thought I made exact and clear question, but ok :)

According the official documentation - AuthMiddlewareStack in Channels supports standard Django authentication, where the user details are stored in the session. So It is needed to check if users are authenticated. But I dont need it, I want to make some kind of public chat, so I dont know how correctly DONT use AuthMiddlewareStack.
My question is : how to write correctly code in routing, that doesnt use authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthMiddlewareStack` combines `AuthMiddleware`, `SessionMiddleware` and `CookieMiddleware`: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html

One thing, that a middleware does is adding some values into the scope. For example the `AuthMiddleware` reads the session-ID from the cookie, looks for the corresponding django user in the session and adds this user into the scope.

If you don't want to use the django users, then you don't have to use the `AuthMiddleware` or the `AuthMiddlewareStack` at all. You can write your own authentication code inside the **init**-method of your Consumer-class and use `self.user` to save your user of the connection.

Your routing could look like this:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        URLRouter(
            [
                url(r"leadusers/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<chatid>[\w-]+)/$", LeadUserConsumer, name='leaduser_consumer'),
            ]
        )
    ),
})
```